# Alerta p/ o programador ao abrir Form (Designer)

Tags: delphi

Quando um programador abrir um formulário específico, gostaria de enviar uma notificação (*`ShowMessage()`*) ao mesmo para ele atentar, por exemplo, aos comentários que estão no cabeçalho do arquivo `.pas` em questão.
Já vi isso num projeto de outra empresa, mas não sei como fazer.

Enfim, como fazer?

Comment: Quando ele abrir o arquivo .pas no Delphi ou quando abrir o programa na aplicação ?

Comment: @VictorZanella Quando abrir o `.pas`. Quero que alerte em modo de *designer*, não em *runtime*.

Comment: Tem um post do stack gringo, que eles citam o `PaletteCreated`. Não sei se esse cara serve pra você, porque ele só alerta quando você criar um componente da paleta no Form. Se isso servir para você, eu posso te passar o protótipo que fiz. Enquanto isso vou tentando encontrar uma outra forma de mostrar a msg. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926320/display-a-warning-when-dropping-a-component-on-a-form-at-design-time

Comment: @VictorZanella Eu já havia visto esse post no *SOen*, mas não é bem o que quero... a ideia é essa mesmo, mas ao acessar um form para desenvolver e não ao arrastar um novo componente. Obrigado.

Comment: Foi o que pensei. Interessante essa funcionalidade. Vou continuar procurando algo ;)

Comment: @VictorZanella Dê uma olhada na mesma [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41060313/6840825) que fiz no *SOen*, meu inglês atrapalha (muito)... mas os comentários podem ser interessantes.

Comment: Ao que me parece, teria como fazer, mas teria que ser escrito um plugin para o Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

Use uma diretiva de compilação no `OnCreate` do formulário:

```
Interface 
{$I YourInc.inc}

Form.Create(Sender:TObject);
Begin
{$IFDEF DESIGNTIME}
showmessage('alguma coisa');
{$ELSE}
// o código normal em tempo de execucao.
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

No KeyDown do Formulário "Pai" tenta aplicar isto.

```
if (( Shift = [ ssctrl, ssalt, ssshift ] ) and ( Key = VK_F12 )) and
    (DebugHook <> 0) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(Self.UnitName);
    Clipboard.AsText := Self.UnitName;
  end;
```

Com isso, quando estiver com o formulário aberto, deve-se apertar os botões do teclado Crtl + Alt + Shift + F12. Ele enviará o nome do formulário como mensagem para auxilia-lo no desenvolvimento.

Comment: `TDelphiUtil`?? Que biblioteca é essa? Não conheço e mesmo após pesquisar na web não encontrei nada...

Comment: Desculpe, utilize DebugHook <> 0 no lugar de TDelphiUtil.isRunningUnderDelphi (acabei pegando de exemplo de meu projeto.) [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DebugHook)

Comment: Legal o seu código, já tenho uma rotina similar na aplicação que chega ao mesmo resultado.  
Mas o que quero conforme a pergunta é outra coisa... quero que ao abrir o formulário no modo de desenvolvimento (não *runtime*), seja exibido um `showmessage` (ou parecido) para o desenvolvedor saber de alguns cuidados a serem tomados no desenvolvimento da tela.

Comment: Procurei até nos confins da terra nessa hora algo parecido que vc queira kkk mas não encontrei, você disse que viu isso em um projeto de outra empresa, mas desconheço, você lembra se pode ser componente de terceiros? Tipo CnPack?

Comment: Não me lembro, faz muito tempo... mas não duvido. Também procurei muito e no máximo, vi que é possível por meio de um *plugin* conforme mencionado na questão http://stackoverflow.com/q/41060313/6840825

Comment: Provável que tenha que utilizar desta forma então meu amigo, pois nativo Delphi acredito que não terá o que vc está procurando.